# WiFi Broadcast Receiver for 2 different classes, how do I cast my activities properly?

Tags: android, casting, broadcastreceiver, wifi-direct

I am following the [WiFi direct guide for Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html) because I am building an app that uses WiFi direct. I also have 2 classes; one is called ClientReceive and one is called HostSend. The Client initiates a connection to the host, and then the host will push data to the client.

I have made a broadcast receiver that listens for state changes when I begin to start my WiFi direct setup:

```
package com.mgamerzproductions.wifidirecttest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDevice;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * A BroadcastReceiver that notifies of important wifi p2p events.
 */
public class WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private WifiP2pManager manager;
    private Channel channel;
    private WiFiActivity activity;

    /**
     * @param manager WifiP2pManager system service
     * @param channel Wifi p2p channel
     * @param Host class (HostSend) for this constructor.
     */
    public WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager manager, Channel channel,
            HostSend activity) {
        super();
        this.manager = manager;
        this.channel = channel;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    /**
     * @param manager WifiP2pManager system service
     * @param channel Wifi p2p channel
     * @param activity activity associated with the receiver
     */
    public WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager manager, Channel channel,
            ClientReceive activity) {
        super();
        this.manager = manager;
        this.channel = channel;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.content.BroadcastReceiver#onReceive(android.content.Context,
     * android.content.Intent)
     */
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

            // UI update to indicate wifi p2p status.
            int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
            if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
                // Wifi Direct mode is enabled
                activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(true);
            } else {
                activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(false);
                //activity.resetData();

            }
            Log.d(Launch.APPTAG, "P2P state changed - " + state);
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

            // request available peers from the wifi p2p manager. This is an
            // asynchronous call and the calling activity is notified with a
            // callback on PeerListListener.onPeersAvailable()
            if (manager != null) {
                /*manager.requestPeers(channel, (PeerListListener) activity.getFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list));*/
            }
            Log.d(Launch.APPTAG, "P2P peers changed");
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

            if (manager == null) {
                return;
            }

            NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

            if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {

                // we are connected with the other device, request connection
                // info to find group owner IP

                HostSend connectionListener = activity;
                manager.requestConnectionInfo(channel, connectionListener);
            } else {
                // It's a disconnect
                activity.resetData();
            }
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            /*DeviceListFragment fragment = (DeviceListFragment) activity.getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);
            fragment.updateThisDevice((WifiP2pDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(
                    WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_P2P_DEVICE));*/

        }
    }
}
```

However, I have another class, ClientReceive, that also needs a receiver because both devices need to setup their WiFi direct and use callbacks (I think that's what these are called? Callbacks to the activity?) to set up a connection. Both classes are a subclass of WiFi activity, which is essentially an empty class that overrides a few methods in Activity with just super.methodname() so the children can access it. IT has some extra methods related to WiFi. I created this so I could avoid casting, but it doesn't work cause the children classes have different methods and if I use WiFiActivity instead of it's subclasses I can't use the subclasses methods.

Is there a way to do this properly? My code is a work in progress (which is why it's kind of ugly) but I'm out of ideas. I have 2 constructors, one from each activity on each device (one is host device, one is client device). What I want to do is share this class between both of the classes but I don't know how to cast the HostSend connectionListener (HostSend) activity properly because I don't know how to cast items like this.

Thanks. Sorry for the long winded explanation.